# Is this a valid proof for the following: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Show in general that $\overline{A \times B} \neq \overline{A}\times \overline{B}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am trying to practice my proofs involving cartesian products of sets and was kind of stuck on this practice question which the text did not provide solutions to. The question is as follows:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Show in general that $\overline{A \times B} \neq \overline{A}\times \overline{B}$

Proof: Assume $\overline{A \times B}$, where $A = \emptyset$ and $B = U$ where $U$ is the universal set such that $\overline{B} = \emptyset$.

$\implies$ Hence, $\overline{A} \neq \emptyset$ and $\overline{B} = \emptyset$

$\implies$ Since $A \times B = \emptyset$, then $\overline{A \times B} \neq \emptyset$. Hence, $\exists (a,b) \in \overline{A \times B}$

$\implies$ Because $B$ is the universal set, then $\overline{B} = \emptyset$. Hence, $\overline{A} \times \overline{B} = \overline{A} \times \emptyset = \emptyset$

$\implies$ thus $(a,b) \not\in \emptyset$. Hence, $\overline{A \times B} \not\subseteq \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$. Since $\overline{A \times B} \not\subseteq \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, it follows that $\overline{A \times B} \neq \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

Given that we have proven that $\overline{A \times B} \not\subseteq \overline{A}\times \overline{B}$ then, $\overline{A \times B} \neq \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

Would this be a correct way of demonstrating the proof or would I be incorrect here ? I am not very sure and was kind of stuck so advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your proof is fine. It assumes that $U \neq \emptyset$ (but if $U = \emptyset$, the claim is false, so that is a reasonable assumption).

Comment: Assuming you mean $\overline A=U\setminus A$, it might be worth using directly the identity $$\overline{A\times B}=(\overline A\times B)\cup (A\times\overline B)\cup (\overline A\times\overline B)$$ and the fact that the above union is disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks good. Just include the case where $U=\emptyset$, which is trivial.

You could also shorten it a bit if you want as follows:

Let $A=\emptyset$ and $B=U$. Now since $A\times B=\emptyset$, $\overline{A}=U$ and $\overline{B}=\emptyset$ we have that $$\overline{A\times B}=\overline{\emptyset}=U\neq \emptyset = \overline{A}\times \overline{B}.$$